# SQL nested sum query

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, sum

I have an SQL table called agent, which looks as follows:

[image: tblAgent]

There is a claim in the data that certain agents are earning a higher salary than the sum of those agents that they supervise. 
I have written the following SQL query to retrieve the agent's name, their personal salary, and the sum of the salaries of those whom they supervise below.
Only agents whose personal salary is greater than 60000 need to be shown.

```
SELECT Agent.Agentname AS ["Supervisor Name"],  Agent.Salary, 
  (SELECT  SUM(Agent.salary) FROM Agent
   WHERE Agent.Supervisor IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY Agent.Supervisor;) 
AS ['Sum of Subordinate Salaries']
FROM Agent
WHERE (((Agent.[Supervisor]) Is Not Null) AND ((Agent.[salary])>=60000))
GROUP BY Agent.AgentName
```

I get an error though which says "Your query does not include the specified expression 'salary' as part of an aggregate function".

How can I rectify the query and get the desired results from it?

Comment: When having same table several times in a query, use qualify the colmuns with table aliases - all over it - to make it clearer.

Comment: @jarlh I have done so, however the same error still occurs.

Comment: Salary is neither aggregated or in the `group by`... This is the problem

Comment: I see no table aliases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 create table #agent (agentno varchar(5),agentname varchar(30),functn varchar(10),supervisor varchar(30),salary int)

Insert into #agent values('A1','Jacobson','Manager','O1',120000), ('A2','Patel','Sales','A1',25000),('A3','Clark','Sales','A1',30000),
('A4','Mabaso','Admin','A1',35000),('B1','Letele','Manager','O1',100000), ('B2','Smit','Sales','B1',35000),    ('B3','Ho','Sales','B1',30000),
('B4','Kruger','Admin','B1',40000),('C1','Mohd','Manager','O1',80000),('C2','Visser','MandR','C1',58000),
('C3','Davie','Admin','C1',42000),('C4','Nakosi','MandR','C1',60000),('C5','Lai','Admin','C4',38000)

select sup.agentname as supervisor_name ,SUM(agn.salary) as subordinate_salary_sum,sup.salary as supervisor_salary
from #agent agn
inner join #agent sup
on agn.supervisor=sup.agentno 
where agn.salary>=60000
group by sup.agentname,sup.salary
```

When using group by, the columns in select statement should be present with the group by statement or should be in an aggregate function.In your query agent.salary was expected in the group by.